# if cell in column is null using Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to set a variable to 0 if the "Independent" column is equal to 0,1,or null. I have been trying something like this:

```
        df["Iflag"] = df.Independent.where((df.Independent == 0) | (df.Independent == 1 )|(df.Independent.isnull())).astype(int)
            Iflag = df[df.Iflag == 0]
            pd.DataFrame(Iflag, columns=["LocIdent","Independent"]).to_csv(Targcsv, mode='ab')
```

I get an error that says I cannot convert NA to integer. This code works when I drop the check to see if Independent is null. My question is, what is the best way to write an if statement that includes null values in Pandas?

Comment: You could just call `df.Independent.fillna(0)` and then your code would work

Comment: basically the issue is that `NaN` cannot be represented using int so you can't cast the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just fill the `nan` values first and then your code would work, `NaN` cannot be represented using ints hence the error.

So something like

```
# fill the nan values
df.Independent = df.Independent.fillna(0)
# set any values that are 1 to 0
df.loc[df.Indepedent == 1, 'Independent'] = 0
# take a view of the df where the value is 0
Iflag = df[df.Independent == 0]
pd.DataFrame(Iflag, columns=["LocIdent","Independent"]).to_csv(Targcsv, mode='ab')
```

It's redundant to check where a value is 0 if all you're going to is set it to 0 again anyway so all you need to do is find the rows where it's 1 already, set these to 0 and then take a view of the df where the condition is satisfied.

Comment: I used .fillna to change nulls to -999, so that I can still evaluate them, and then switch them back to null at the end of my code. Thanks for this!